# iOS Storyboard: set ImageView width and height not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

I have an image need to display use UIImageView and I use storyboard to set the view's height and width in the size inspector and set this view's horizontal centre in the super view.But when i click update frames in resolve auto layout issues ,it always uses the image resource size.How can I do for this ?[my constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B97pO.jpg)

Comment: Please provide more information (other views in viewcontroller, all constraints you use, maybe a screenshot of you storyboard,...)

Comment: did you give constant height and width to UIImageView?

Comment: I set the height and width in the size inspector.But it don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add width and height constrains to the imageView.

[image]

Comment: thanks,it resolves my problem.But I still can't understand why it does not work in the  size inspector .I already set the view width and height.

Comment: when using auto-layout constrains  the size inspector no longer plays a role in determining the size of elements.